# pregmatch break a where clause

Tags: php, sql, regex

**THE QUESTION ABOVE ^^^^^ DOES NOT HAVE THE CORRECT ANSWER**

as the accepted answer in that question leads to a MYSQL page to break the query apart, still i need the solution in PHP and the link in the answer provided in this question is actually what i need .

I am trying to create a useful array out of `where` clauses in SQL

well let's assume these :

`where a=b and b=c or d=g and (a=f or x=6)`

`where a=b and b='d and f' or d=g and (a=f or x=6)`

`where a=b and b="d and f (or just text)" or d=g and (a=f or x=6)`

`where "a"=b and`b`="Note that colum names might be quoted differently in different databases" or d=g and (a=f or x=6)`

`where "a"='b' and`b`="as well as values" or d=g and (a=f or x=6)`

`where "a"='b' and`b`="multiple levels" or d=g and (a=f or x=6 or (x=5 and v=7))`

i want to try and break any where clause (with key=value ... aka no sub queries) into useful array maybe ?
something like :

```
x= array(
array('a' => 'b' , 'b' => 'c'),
array('d' => 'g' , array(array('a' => 'f'),array('x' => '6')),
);
```

where AND are in one array OR in new array

or any other format, just to be able to rebuild the whole query into whatever i want.

is preg_match enough here ?

Comment: What is the use of this outside of a homework assignment?

Comment: @Ronan Dejhero each where are individual question?

Comment: A SQL parser would make more sense here.

Comment: @Ronan Dejhero I am also trying these one , but not succeded yet. Thanks for posting these question. I am not able to post question because it's blocked

Comment: I am posting one of my example R&D code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [@Jack's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17542573/pregmatch-break-a-where-clause#comment25514483_17542573), an SQL parser would make sense here.  For example, using [PHP SQL Parser](https://code.google.com/p/php-sql-parser/):

```
$sql = 'where a=b and b=c or d=g and (a=f or x=6)';

require_once('php-sql-parser.php');
$parser = new PHPSQLParser();
$parsed = $parser->parse($sql);
print_r($parsed);
```

Comment: Please just close against the duplicate, we have this answer on this website already, a link per a comment is enough IMHO to keep things straight: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12109334/367456

Comment: @hakre: I question whether that's really a dupe; the questions are asking different things - this one is asking about parsing a particular subclause, whereas the other one is asking about parsing entire commands.  Whilst both can be done with the same tool, that is not immediately obvious from the linked answer.

Answer (score 0):

The below function I have used for my codeigniter framework - for updating a table

```
function updateCT($options = array(),$where=array())
{
    // required values
    if(!$this->_required(
        array('id'),
        $where)
    ) return false;

    // set values for updating
    foreach($options as $key=>$val)
    {
        $this->db->set($key,$val);
    }

    // set where clause for updating
    foreach($where as $key=>$val)
    {
        $this->db->where($key,$val);
    }

    $this->db->update(TBL_COMPANY_TYPE);
    return $this->db->affected_rows();
}
```

For defining condition and clause the array format will be like below:-

```
$options=array(
                 'key1'=>array('val1' , 'and'), 
                 'key2'=>array('val2' , 'or'),
             );
```

now process the array like below:-

```
foreach($options as $key=>$val)
{
    foreach($val as $value=>$condition)
    {
        // now write sql format as your framework
    }
}
```

Comment: How does this help parse the `WHERE` clause from an existing SQL string into a data structure such as that the OP is after (which is what the question is asking, to my reading)?

Comment: @eggyal I think OP is trying to parse an array and process that array to form "where" clause. OP wants to avoid manually creating the where clause. My above code will work as a Generic function... But till now the above function is on R&D phase. I need to do many update on this function...

Comment: @ripa: If I'm not reading the question wrong, the opposite is the case. And if you do R&D look for existing solutions as well. They might show you a better way how to do things (and might be already useable). So good for learning *and* getting things done.

Comment: @hakre if opposite is the OP's question then I am posting a backtrack process. I am editing my answer...

Comment: negative vote!!!!! it's OK. But please give reason...