# Separate SQL commands in PHP

Tags: php, postgresql

I have a (dynamically generated) file that includes a lot of SQL Statements that contain only data definition.

Usually, I run the whole script as a single transaction via `pg_query`. Is there an efficient and safe way to separate the SQL commands in PHP in order to split them in several transactions?

Like splitting the whole string by `;` but avoiding errors due to usage of `;` within quotes?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse SELECT clause of SQL queries into a PHP array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968690/parse-select-clause-of-sql-queries-into-a-php-array)

Comment: Or this? https://github.com/greenlion/PHP-SQL-Parser

Comment: :-( yes, unfortunately

Comment: If you create that sql file itself, you can create a set of characters behind every query to split on (eg. /**woooopie**/)

Comment: "unfortunately"? Why? Anything not working with the two linked solutions?

Comment: Add special separator into generated file between queries. Separator must be of structure that is not likely to appear in any of query contents. E.g. `/** -- SEPARATOR 12312335345345 -- **/`